# Cannot fix "inconsistent use of tab and white space" and "does not match any other indentation level" errors in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a section of my code that is spitting the error "does not match any other indentation level" or spitting "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces". I have tried so many different things just to get this code to run but no matter what I do it still errors. I have used online tab -> space websites such as https://tabstospaces.com/ . I have also done so many google searches to try and find some kind of help. The full code can be found below, but I believe the troublesome section is right here:

```
if man.jumpCount >= -10:
    neg = 1

    if man.jumpCount < 0:
        neg = -1


    if canGoDown():
        if neg == -1:
            if canGoDown() and man.y + gravity + man.height > gameY:
                man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            else:
                man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1
```

I am using python 3.8 with notepad ++.

I have tried for quite awhile now to fix this. I have used multiple online "replace tab with spaces", I have tried retyping the white spaces multiple times as well. I've had this issue before but it has fixed itself without me knowing how. This time I cannot get it to fix. Any help will be amazing!

Full code:

```
import pygame
import time
import ctypes


#Gets screen resolution and assigns to resX and resY

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
resX,resY = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)

print('Resolution is: ', resX,resY)

pygame.init()


#Sets display size

gameX,gameY = 750,562

win = pygame.display.set_mode((gameX,gameY))
pygame.display.set_caption('Squared: The Game')

#Scales background image

bg = pygame.image.load('background.jpeg')
bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (gameX,gameY))
boungindRect = bg.get_rect()

objectList = []

gravity = 5


class cube(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 5
        self.isJump = False
        self.jumpCount = 10
        self.hitbox = (self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height)

    def move(self):


        pass

    def draw(self,spawnX,spawnY):

        self.hitbox = (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (self.x, self.y, self.width,self.height))   

        pass

    pass

class object():

    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):

        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw(self,color):

        self.hitbox = (self.x,self.y,self.width,self.height)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2)

        pygame.draw.rect(win, color, (self.x,self.y, self.width, self.height))   


        pass

    def collision():

        print('Collided')

        pass

def makeObject(win,color,boundingBox):     #x,y,width,height):

    maxX = x + width
    maxY = y + height



    pygame.draw.rect(win, color, boundingBox)       #(x,y,width,height))

    xList = [x,maxX]
    yList = [y,maxY]

    return xList,yList


    pass


def ldr1():

    objectList.clear()

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,255,0),(400,350,100,20))
    object1X = [400,500]
    object1Y = [350,370]
    object1 = [object1X,object1Y]
    objectList.append(object1)



    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), (250,375,100,20))
    object2X = [250,350]
    object2Y = [375,395]
    object2 = [object2X,object2Y]
    objectList.append(object2)



    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,255,255), (50, 350,20, 100))
    object3X = [50, 70]
    object3Y= [350,450]
    object3 = [object3X,object3Y]
    objectList.append(object3)



    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,0), (100,475,50,50))
    object4X = [100,150]
    object4Y = [475,525]
    object4 = [object4X,object4Y]
    objectList.append(object4)



    pass


def updateScreen():


    win.blit(bg,(0,0))
    man.draw(250,250)

    ldr1()

    #pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (50,50,50,50))   



    pygame.display.update()


    pass


def callCurrentLvl():

    ldr1()

    pass


def canGoDown():

    return canGo(0,-man.vel)

    pass

def canGoUp():

    return canGo(0,man.vel)

    pass

def canGoRight():

    print('checking canGoRight')

    print('man.vel is ', man.vel)

    #print('The list of objects is ' , objectList)

    return canGo(man.vel,0)

    pass

def canGoLeft():

    return canGo(-man.vel,0)

    pass

def canGoY(thisY = 0):


    if minY <= man.y + thisY <= maxY or minY <= (man.y + man.height-20 + thisY) <= maxY:

        #Activates if inside a hitbox


        print("cannot travel Y")
        return False

        pass
    else:


        print('can travel Y')

        return True

    pass


def canGo(thisX = 0,thisY = 0):

    """
    Is only checking the farthest right box... because it returns, breaking the loop after just one iteration.

    """

    print('checking can Go ')

    #print(objectList)

    for curObject in objectList:

        print('\n\n\n',curObject)

        objectsX = curObject[0]
        objectsY = curObject[1]

        minX = objectsX[0]
        minY = objectsY[0]

        maxX = objectsX[1]
        maxY = objectsY[1]

        print(man.x, '   ', man.y)

        print('-------')
        print(minX,maxX)
        print(minY,maxY)
        print('-------')
        #print('cur vel ',man.vel,'  ', man.x,man.y)


        #First if statement checks if both bottom x and top x are inside the points.

        #second if statement does that with y

        inX = False
        inY = False

        if minX <= man.x + thisX<= maxX and minX <= (man.x + man.width + thisX) <= maxX:

            print('Inside x range')

            inX = True


            pass

        else:

            print('Outside x range')

            pass



        if minY <= man.y + thisY <= maxY or minY <= (man.y + man.height-20 +thisY ) <= maxY:

            #Activates if inside a hitbox

            print('Inside y range')

            inY = True

            pass

        else:

            print('Outside y range')

            pass

        if inX and inY:

            print('inX and inY is True')

            return False

            pass

        else:

            print('one or the other is false')

            print(inX, inY)

            #return True    

            pass


        pass
    return True

    pass




"""

Actual game

"""

man = cube(60,490, 40, 40)


#main loop

run = True

while run:


    callCurrentLvl()

    #print(objectList)

    pygame.time.delay(25)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


    #for objects in objectList:

        #print(objects)


        #object1 = object(objects)

        #pass






    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > (man.vel-3): #and canGoLeft():
        print('Left key held')

        print(man.x)

        man.x = man.x - man.vel

        pass

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < gameX - man.width - man.vel + 5 and canGoRight():

        print('Going right')

        print(man.x)

        man.x = man.x + man.vel


        pass


    if not(man.isJump):
        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
            man.isJump = True
            man.right = False
            man.left = False
            man.walkCount = 0
    else:

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and man.jumpCount >= -10:

            print('hammering')

            pass


        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
                        neg = 1

            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                                neg = -1


            if canGoDown():
                if neg == -1:
                    if canGoDown() and man.y + gravity + man.height > gameY:
                        man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
                else:
                        man.y -= (man.jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            man.jumpCount -= 1

        else:
            man.isJump = False
            man.jumpCount = 10

    #gravity

    if canGoDown() and man.y + gravity + man.height < gameY:

        man.y = man.y + gravity


    updateScreen()



    pass


pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Please include (and look at) the _full_ error message. It tells you precisely where is the problem.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this error but Venky is correct that the better syntax is to just use elif

Comment: This is a massive amount of code and you have not provided any traceback (which would point at the erroneous line). Also, why do you have all those blank lines and unneeded pass statements? Please post the traceback and reduce the code to the minimum possible to reliably reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

Near the end of the file, at line 402:

```
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
                        neg = 1

            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                                neg = -1
```

Move `neg = 1` to the left so it corresponds to the next `if`:

```
        if man.jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1

            if man.jumpCount < 0:
                                neg = -1
```

I guess the mistake is caused by the following sequence of events: you have been writing your code in some editor, which doesn't convert tab to spaces and assumes that tab corresponds to 8 spaces. When you used an online tool for converting tabs to spaces you used the default settings for tab equal to 4 spaces. Because of that you get inconsistent indentation in your file.

Answer (score -3):

in your code "cango(): and addnewgame" method you have used in 'while' loop 'if' condition same indent to the another 'if' condition this is the error i think ..... instead of 'if' in same indent 'if' you use a better coding for ('elif': it is the correct way your query)

Comment: While it is a logical error, it is not the syntax error that the OP observes.

Comment: no sir it is syntax error, same indent in 'if' condition is not possible 'if' then same indent we have to use 'elif' or 'else'

Comment: It is perfectly fine to have several if statements at same indent. Both elif and else are not mandatory.